# How to close the app, but keep it in the background (sleep)

Tags: cordova, cordova-android

In Android: You know how when you keep pressing the back button, the app "closes", goes to sleep, ready to resume? That's what I want to accomplish with Cordova.

The problem I'm facing is that when my app closes, it actually exits. When I open it again, it doesn't resume, it completely restarts.

I tried both `window.navigator.app.exitApp()` and `window.navigator.app.backHistory()` and they both completely close the app.

Comment: https://github.com/tomloprod/cordova-plugin-appminimize   Is this, perhaps, what you need?

Comment: @AnjilDhamala put it in an answer. You deserves me votes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a Cordova plugin that should do what you want.
[Cordova Plugin App Minimize](https://github.com/tomloprod/cordova-plugin-appminimize)

If you are using Ionic Framework, you'd want the Ionic wrapper for the plugin. 
[Ionic Native App Minimize](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/app-minimize/)

**Please note that the plugin mentions that it is only supported in Android platform.**